# JavaFX Disable KeyCombinations

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx-8

Is there a way in JavaFX to disable all the key combinations like *Windows+D, Ctrl+Alt+Del, Alt+Tab* such that the user is unable to move out of the application using the keyboard?

Any leads on this?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but I imagine you will have to use JNI to disable the keyboard shortcuts whilst your program is running or while your JFrame is in focus

Comment: I don't know about the others but Ctrl+Alt+Del is a Os-Security-feature. There will be no built in solution to disable that in java.

Comment: Not only is there no built-in way to disable Ctrl-Alt-Del in Java, there's no possible way it could be done. Ctrl-Alt-Del is intercepted at a very low level in the operating system, as AIUI not propagated beyond that. So the JVM never even receives the event.

Comment: so other events like windows+D can not be captured as well??